# How to plot polar formed complex numbers?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw the figure below in LaTeX and am having a bit of a difficulty. How can I do it?

[image]

```
%\usepackage[dvips,pdftex]{graphicx}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage[unicode=true,bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,breaklinks=true,backref=true,linkcolor=black,colorlinks=true]%
{hyperref}%
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{30}
%TCIDATA{OutputFilter=latex2.dll}
%TCIDATA{Version=5.50.0.2953}
%TCIDATA{LastRevised=Thursday, March 14, 2019 23:50:47}
%TCIDATA{<META NAME="GraphicsSave" CONTENT="32">}
%TCIDATA{<META NAME="SaveForMode" CONTENT="1">}
%TCIDATA{BibliographyScheme=Manual}
%BeginMSIPreambleData
\providecommand{\U}[1]{\protect\rule{.1in}{.1in}}
%EndMSIPreambleData
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.5cm} \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0cm} \setlength{\textheight}{24cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16.5cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\[\]
\begin{center}
%\tiny,\small,\large,\Large,\LARGE, \huge,\Huge,\HUGE
{ \Large \sc Universidade Federal do Maranhão}
\vskip 0.5cm
{ \Large \sc Centro de Ciências Exatas e Tecnologia}
\vskip 0.5cm {\Large \sc Matheus Rodrigues Linhares Guimarães}
\vskip 3 cm {\LARGE \sc \textbf{VARIÁVEIS COMPLEXAS}}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \[
    \includegraphics[width=100mm]{./Figuras/capa5.png}
    \]
\end{figure}

\vskip 2cm
\vfill
{\sc 2019.1}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}%


\end{document}
```

After doing the code, how do I put it in place of \ begin {figure} [H]
        \ centering
        \ [
        \ includegraphics [width = 100mm] {./ Figures / layer5.png}
        ]
    \ end {figure}
so you do not need figures?

Comment: This question could benefit from a textual description of what you are trying to achieve. That way, when somebody wants to do something similar, searching for those terms will help them find this question and it's answer. Specifically, mention the part(s) of the diagram which are not being drawn to your desire. Something like "How to draw concentric circles" or "How to draw a line segment whose endpoint lies on the edge of a circle" or whatever you feel best describes the part you can't draw in your image. This will also help your question from seeming too broad.

Comment: @Davy M So how can I do it?
I put this in the description of the question?

Comment: @MatheusGuimaraes Yes, I would add it after you mention that you are having a bit of difficulty, a more exact description of what parts are giving you difficulty. This probably isn't a priority since you already got your answer, but it will likely help other people who want to do something similar so they can find your question and the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Note:** The codes are arranged in "quality-increasing" order in my opinion, i.e. the best one is the last one.

---

Like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,-4)--(0,4) node[above] {$Im$} (-4,0)--(4,0) node[right] {$Re$};
\draw[dashed] (0,0) circle (3) circle (2);
\coordinate (a) at (80:3);
\coordinate (b) at (3,0);
\coordinate (m) at (25:2);
\coordinate (n) at (-95:2);
\coordinate (p) at (145:2);
\coordinate (o) at (0,0);
\fill[black] (a) circle (2pt) (b) circle (2pt) (m) circle (2pt) (n) circle (2pt) (p) circle (2pt) (2,0) circle (2pt);
\draw (a) node[above right] {$z=|z|e^{i\theta}$};
\draw (b) node[below] {$|z|$};
\draw (2,0) node[below] {$|z|^{1/3}$};
\draw (m) node[right] {$|z|^{1/3}e^{i\theta/3}$};
\draw (n) node[below] {$|z|^{1/3}e^{i(\theta+4\pi)/3}$};
\draw (p) node[above] {$|z|^{1/3}e^{i(\theta+2\pi)/3}$};
\draw (.1,1.5)--(0,1.5) node[left] {$i$};
\draw (1.5,.1)--(1.5,0) node[below] {$1$};
\draw (0,0)--(a) (0,0)--(m) (0,0)--(n) (0,0)--(p);
\draw[dashed] (m)--(n)--(p)--cycle;
\pic[draw,dashed,thick,"$\theta$",angle radius=0.8cm,angle eccentricity=1.3] {angle=b--o--a};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Improved version:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]
\draw (0,-4)--(0,4) node[above] {$Im$} (-4,0)--(4,0) node[right] {$Re$};
\draw[dashed] (0,0) circle (3) circle (2);
\coordinate (a) at (80:3);
\coordinate (b) at (3,0);
\coordinate (m) at (25:2);
\coordinate (n) at (-95:2);
\coordinate (p) at (145:2);
\coordinate (o) at (0,0);
\draw (a) node[above right] {$z=|z|e^{i\theta}$};
\draw (b) node[below right] {$|z|$};
\draw (2,0) node[below left=0cm and -2em] {$|z|^{1/3}$};
\draw (m) node[right] {$|z|^{1/3}e^{i\theta/3}$};
\draw (n) node[below] {$|z|^{1/3}e^{i(\theta+4\pi)/3}$};
\draw (p) node[above] {$|z|^{1/3}e^{i(\theta+2\pi)/3}$};
\draw (.1,1.5)--(0,1.5) node[left] {$i$};
\draw (1.5,.1)--(1.5,0) node[below] {$1$};
\draw (0,0)--(a) (0,0)--(m) (0,0)--(n) (0,0)--(p);
\draw[dashed] (m)--(n)--(p)--cycle;
\end{scope}
\pic[draw,dashed,thick,"$\theta$",angle radius=0.8cm,angle eccentricity=1.3] {angle=b--o--a};
\fill[black] (a) circle (2pt) (b) circle (2pt) (m) circle (2pt) (n) circle (2pt) (p) circle (2pt) (2,0) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks to [@marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot), I think this figure is more mathematically true ;-)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]
\draw (0,-4)--(0,4) node[above] {$Im$} (-4,0)--(4,0) node[right] {$Re$};
\draw[dashed] (0,0) circle (3) circle (2);
\coordinate (a) at (80:3);
\coordinate (b) at (3,0);
\coordinate (m) at (80/3:2);
\coordinate (n) at ({80/3-120}:2);
\coordinate (p) at ({80/3+120}:2);
\coordinate (o) at (0,0);
\draw (a) node[above right] {$z=|z|e^{i\theta}$};
\draw (b) node[below right] {$|z|$};
\draw (2,0) node[below left=0cm and -2em] {$|z|^{1/3}$};
\draw (m) node[right] {$|z|^{1/3}e^{i\theta/3}$};
\draw (n) node[below] {$|z|^{1/3}e^{i(\theta+4\pi)/3}$};
\draw (p) node[above] {$|z|^{1/3}e^{i(\theta+2\pi)/3}$};
\draw (.1,1.5)--(0,1.5) node[left] {$i$};
\draw (1.5,.1)--(1.5,0) node[below] {$1$};
\draw (0,0)--(a) (0,0)--(m) (0,0)--(n) (0,0)--(p);
\draw[dashed] (m)--(n)--(p)--cycle;
\end{scope}
\pic[draw,dashed,thick,"$\theta$",angle radius=0.8cm,angle eccentricity=1.3] {angle=b--o--a};
\fill[black] (a) circle (2pt) (b) circle (2pt) (m) circle (2pt) (n) circle (2pt) (p) circle (2pt) (2,0) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another choice: `\Im` instead of `Im` and `\Re` instead of `Re` ([@Sebastiano](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117876/sebastiano)'s request):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]
\draw (0,-4)--(0,4) node[above] {$\Im$} (-4,0)--(4,0) node[right] {$\Re$};
\draw[dashed] (0,0) circle (3) circle (2);
\coordinate (a) at (80:3);
\coordinate (b) at (3,0);
\coordinate (m) at (80/3:2);
\coordinate (n) at ({80/3-120}:2);
\coordinate (p) at ({80/3+120}:2);
\coordinate (o) at (0,0);
\draw (a) node[above right] {$z=|z|e^{i\theta}$};
\draw (b) node[below right] {$|z|$};
\draw (2,0) node[below left=0cm and -2em] {$|z|^{1/3}$};
\draw (m) node[right] {$|z|^{1/3}e^{i\theta/3}$};
\draw (n) node[below] {$|z|^{1/3}e^{i(\theta+4\pi)/3}$};
\draw (p) node[above] {$|z|^{1/3}e^{i(\theta+2\pi)/3}$};
\draw (.1,1.5)--(0,1.5) node[left] {$i$};
\draw (1.5,.1)--(1.5,0) node[below] {$1$};
\draw (0,0)--(a) (0,0)--(m) (0,0)--(n) (0,0)--(p);
\draw[dashed] (m)--(n)--(p)--cycle;
\end{scope}
\pic[draw,dashed,thick,"$\theta$",angle radius=0.8cm,angle eccentricity=1.3] {angle=b--o--a};
\fill[black] (a) circle (2pt) (b) circle (2pt) (m) circle (2pt) (n) circle (2pt) (p) circle (2pt) (2,0) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks to [@JasperHabicht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/47927/jasper-habicht) in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479890/156344), now I can optimize the separating space between node texts and the line:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles,positioning}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\contourlength{2pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,-4)--(0,4) node[above] {$\Im$} (-4,0)--(4,0) node[right] {$\Re$};
\draw[dashed] (0,0) circle (3) circle (2);
\coordinate (a) at (80:3);
\coordinate (b) at (3,0);
\coordinate (m) at (80/3:2);
\coordinate (n) at ({80/3-120}:2);
\coordinate (p) at ({80/3+120}:2);
\coordinate (o) at (0,0);
\draw (a) node[above right] {\contour{white}{$z=|z|e^{i\theta}$}};
\draw (b) node[below right] {\contour{white}{$|z|$}};
\draw (2,0) node[below left=0cm and -2em] {\contour{white}{$|z|^{1/3}$}};
\draw (m) node[right] {\contour{white}{$|z|^{1/3}e^{i\theta/3}$}};
\draw (n) node[below] {\contour{white}{$|z|^{1/3}e^{i(\theta+4\pi)/3}$}};
\draw (p) node[above] {\contour{white}{$|z|^{1/3}e^{i(\theta+2\pi)/3}$}};
\draw (.1,1.5)--(0,1.5) node[left] {\contour{white}{$i$}};
\draw (1.5,.1)--(1.5,0) node[below] {\contour{white}{$1$}};
\draw (0,0)--(a) (0,0)--(m) (0,0)--(n) (0,0)--(p);
\draw[dashed] (m)--(n)--(p)--cycle;
\pic[draw,dashed,thick,"$\theta$",angle radius=0.8cm,angle eccentricity=1.3] {angle=b--o--a};
\fill[black] (a) circle (2pt) (b) circle (2pt) (m) circle (2pt) (n) circle (2pt) (p) circle (2pt) (2,0) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Your code is not compilable because of a conflict (?) between `babel` and `quotes` (I don't know if it is true).

We can fix it by not using `quotes` anymore:

```
%\usepackage[dvips,pdftex]{graphicx}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage[unicode=true,bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,breaklinks=true,backref=true,linkcolor=black,colorlinks=true]%
{hyperref}%
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{30}
%TCIDATA{OutputFilter=latex2.dll}
%TCIDATA{Version=5.50.0.2953}
%TCIDATA{LastRevised=Thursday, March 14, 2019 23:50:47}
%TCIDATA{<META NAME="GraphicsSave" CONTENT="32">}
%TCIDATA{<META NAME="SaveForMode" CONTENT="1">}
%TCIDATA{BibliographyScheme=Manual}
%BeginMSIPreambleData
\providecommand{\U}[1]{\protect\rule{.1in}{.1in}}
%EndMSIPreambleData
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.5cm} \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0cm} \setlength{\textheight}{24cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16.5cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{center}
%\tiny,\small,\large,\Large,\LARGE, \huge,\Huge,\HUGE
{ \Large \sc Universidade Federal do Maranhão}
\vskip 0.5cm
{ \Large \sc Centro de Ciências Exatas e Tecnologia}
\vskip 0.5cm {\Large \sc Matheus Rodrigues Linhares Guimarães}
\vskip 3 cm {\LARGE \sc \textbf{VARIAVEIS COMPLEXAS}}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]
\draw (0,-4)--(0,4) node[above] {$Im$} (-4,0)--(4,0) node[right] {$Re$};
\draw[dashed] (0,0) circle (3) circle (2);
\coordinate (a) at (80:3);
\coordinate (b) at (3,0);
\coordinate (m) at (80/3:2);
\coordinate (n) at ({80/3-120}:2);
\coordinate (p) at ({80/3+120}:2);
\coordinate (o) at (0,0);
\draw (a) node[above right] {$z=|z|e^{i\theta}$};
\draw (b) node[below right] {$|z|$};
\draw (2,0) node[below left=0cm and -2em] {$|z|^{1/3}$};
\draw (m) node[right] {$|z|^{1/3}e^{i\theta/3}$};
\draw (n) node[below] {$|z|^{1/3}e^{i(\theta+4\pi)/3}$};
\draw (p) node[above] {$|z|^{1/3}e^{i(\theta+2\pi)/3}$};
\draw (.1,1.5)--(0,1.5) node[left] {$i$};
\draw (1.5,.1)--(1.5,0) node[below] {$1$};
\draw (0,0)--(a) (0,0)--(m) (0,0)--(n) (0,0)--(p);
\draw[dashed] (m)--(n)--(p)--cycle;
\end{scope}
\pic[draw,dashed,thick,angle radius=0.8cm,angle eccentricity=1.3] {angle=b--o--a};
\draw (45:0.8) node[above right] {$\theta$};
\fill[black] (a) circle (2pt) (b) circle (2pt) (m) circle (2pt) (n) circle (2pt) (p) circle (2pt) (2,0) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\vskip 2cm
\vfill
{\sc 2019.1}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}%


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes.
I'll send you my base code.

Comment: I want to put image where it is o: \ begin {figure} [H]
\ centering
\ [
\ includegraphics [width = 100mm] {./ Figures / layer5.png}
\]
\ end {figure}
what needs to be done?

Comment: @MatheusGuimaraes It is hard to copy your code in comments, because there are some `%` comments in the code. Please add it to the question, and I will see if I can help.

Comment: @JouleV I'd use `\Im` e `\Re` commands.

Comment: @Sebastiano I would use it also. But the image given shows *Im* (which can mean *I* x *m*) and *Re* (which can mean *R* x *e*).

Comment: @JouleV Yes, I saw the picture. But not all images or codes are correct :-)

Comment: I saw the code corrected, it was perfect.
Wonderful
Thank you so much, it became incredible.

Comment: @JouleV is it possible to increase the image a bit as in the picture I sent on the cover?
She's a little short.

Comment: @MatheusGuimaraes You can use option `[scale=1.5]` for example. Add it right after `\begin{tikzpicture}`.